# Javascript - Select first element of child of child of element

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="list">
<div class="items">
    <ul>
        <li>IMPORTANT</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to select the First "li" in the first "ul" in the div "items" in the div "list" via Javascript.

Comment: What browser compatibility?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any combination of `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
var uls = divs[0].getElementsByTagName('ul');
var lis = uls[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
var li = lis[0];
//// li is now the first list element of the first list inside the first div with the class "items"
```

It is easier if you give some elements an id, then you can use an
`getElementById` instead of the clunky `getElements_` and don't have to deal with arrays:

```
var div = document.getElementById('items');  // If the right <div> has an id="items"
var uls = div.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var lis = uls[0].getElementsByTagName('li'); // Or instead of uls[0] give the right ul and id
var li = lis[0];                             // Or instead of lis[0] give the right li and id
```

The easiest solution is probably to use a library like jQuery, in which you can do this with selectors:

```
var li = $('div.items:first ul:first li:first');
```

**edit**:
I'd recommend David Thomas's solution if you can't use jQuery and have no problem with excluding older browsers (mainly IE7 or lower).

Comment: the div has a class of items, not an id of items.

Comment: Missed that, I've fixed it

Answer (score 7):

If you're targeting modern browsers, I'd suggest:

```
var importantLi = document.querySelector('.list .items li');
```

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t13)</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

your div would normally be `<div id="items">` or `<div id="items" class="items">` since a div with id is unique on a page.

Then

```
firstLi = document.getElementById("items").firstChild.firstChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **JQuery**, it's more easy to target

```
$(".list .items ul:first li:first")
```

OR

```
$("div.list div.items ul li").first()
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/hyu5s/1/)**

Answer (score -2):

you can try this `<script>$('.items ul li:first').val()</script>`